# Who are the Corlies of Arizona?

Tags: meaning, stephen-king, carrie

In [Part I of *Carrie*](https://archive.org/stream/StephenKingCarriev5.0pdf?ref=ol#page/n39/mode/2up/search/Arizona), Stephen King writes:

> Like Flatlands Society, the Rosicrucians, or the Corlies of Arizona, who are positive that the atomic bomb does not work, these unfortunates are flying in the face of logic with their heads in the sand-and beg your pardon for the mixed metaphor.

Knowing that The Flatlands Society, which I assume is an alternative title for "The Flatearth Society", and Rosicrucians are pseudoscientic movements, I assume the Corlies of Arizona would be aswell, however I haven't been able to find any groups bearing such a title. What exactly is the "Corlies of Arizona", an informal name perhaps for an organisation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's likely that this is an invention of Stephen King. As you've noted the only references to said group are *Carrie* itself. The idea being that these are groups with a conspiracy-based view of the world.

Comment: The only references to "Flatlands Society" are *Carrie* itself too, but that one is a malapropism for something in the real world. Couldn't it be the same with "Corlies" - it's misspelled or miswritten but it is or was a real group?